# Can C# file restrict for adding specific access modifier variables?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I have a requirement that all my .cs file variables should be protected. Is there a way to restrict adding private access modifier type variables to this type of files?

Comment: I would question the legitimacy of such a requirement. It's rarely correct that inheriting classes should directly interact with base data members.

Comment: Can you explain **why** you want to do this @Dinidu ?

Comment: @mjwills We create extension projects for different regions to be able to support region specific functionalities. So as a core application developer I should make sure to give the ability to use each and every class variable in that extension layer. This is the reason to restrict of using private variables

Answer (score 1):

Though that's a typical requirement but if it's a organization coding rule then you can use Microsoft `FxCop` static code analysis tool and define your own rule set; which then per your setting may cause the build to fail or throw warning if the rule isn't met

Comment: Can I add this as an extension for VS 2013?

Comment: @Dinidu, yes but you also have a Nuget package for that https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers/

Answer (score 0):

You might use [StyleCop](https://github.com/StyleCop/StyleCop) or implement a [custom code analyser](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/How-To-Write-a-C%23-Analyzer-and-Code-Fix)